# Is it possible to overwrite the undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

like

```
function myFunction(){
    var undefined = "abc";
}
```

If its possible then how to restrict not to allow that?

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to overwrite the undefined in javascript?

If by "the undefined" you mean the global `undefined` variable, then no. Since EcmaScript 5, it is [specified as non-writable](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.1.3). However, older browsers don't adhere that spec, so it is overwritable in legacy engines. You cannot really prevent it in them, but [always reset it by `undefined = void 0;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5021133/1048572). If you still worry and want to know how to protect your own scripts, check the question [How dangerous is it in JavaScript, really, to assume undefined is not overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8783510/1048572).

> like `function myFunction(){ var undefined = "abc"; }`

That's a different thing. You can always declare a local variable with the name `undefined` (shadowing the global one) and assign arbitrary values to it.

Comment: +1. I think the confusion comes from thinking that `undefined` is a keyword instead of a property of the global object. Some syntax highlighters highlight it as if it were a keyword, probably adding to the confusion (even SO does this).

Answer (score 7):

Some browsers allow it, the best way to restrict it is avoiding it.

But... some are using this technique to preserve the undefined:

```
(function(undefined){

})()
```

They get a variable called `undefined` but don't pass a value which gives `undefined` the `undefined` value.

From jQuery's source code:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    ...
    ...
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to overwrite undefined.

This question has good solutions for working around that problem - [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: That page states "As @CMS pointed out, this has been patched in ECMAScript 5th ed., and undefined is non-writable."