# How to override window and undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I have seen some examples like this

```
(function($, window, undefined) {
  ...
  // Do awesome stuff
  ...
})(jQuery, this);
```

I understand passing jQuery as a paramter and receiving as $.

This is done to avoid conflict between jquery's $ and any global variable $ ( defined by mistake or by some third party library ).

Why do people pass `this` and receive as `window` and also receive `undefined` in function parameter ?

***Is there any way we can override window and undefined ?***

PS: I have already tried this in Chrome

```
undefined = 2; // 2
undefined == 2; // false
```

It proves undefined can not be over-ridden.

Comment: better take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2716188/1671639)

Comment: This question has already been answered for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021133/get-undefined-if-window-undefined-is-overwritten

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for the link. It says undefined can be changed but I am not able to over-ride it.

Comment: @blunderboy yes it can be overwritten only within a function scope like here in a closure `(function() {
   console.log(undefined); //undefined
   var undefined = 10; console.log(undefined);//returns 10
})();`

Comment: @C-link It is not duplicate because I want to ask **How to override undefined and window variables** in specific ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
function test () {
    var undefined = 2; // 2
    console.log(undefined == 2); // true

    var window = 5; // 5
    console.log(window == 5); // true
}
```

I believe you can alter the value of `undefined` and `window` inside a `function`, but not in the `global` scope